# Blend two divs at their meeting point

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I seamlessly blend the colors of two divs along their meeting point border? Basically looking for a gradient that will roll between them. CSS, JavaScript, pick your poison. Obviously bonus points for CSS.

Tried box-shadow but I can't really control it along their meeting edge as much as I'd like, plus it bleeds all over.

http://jsfiddle.net/q131p8w2/2/

```
div:nth-child(1) {
    background: skyblue;
    height:150px;
    width:300px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
div:nth-child(2) {
    background: black;
    height:150px;
    width:300px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This snippet could be a lead to something.

```css
div:nth-child(1) {
  color: skyblue;
}
div:nth-child(2) {
  color: black;
}
div {
  position: relative;
  background: currentColor;
  height: 150px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
div:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background: linear-gradient(currentColor, transparent);
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: That's a brilliant technique and I ended up tweaking it to work. Using transparent gave too much of a harsh edge, so I just applied it to the first div and used the two distinct colors. http://jsfiddle.net/q131p8w2/5/ Thanks so much!

Comment: that's the way to go if you don't need flexible code. I like having DRY code :)

Comment: @daveycroqet Also, I think another lead could have been to use linear-backgrounds instead of a regular one, and make the `<div>`s overlap each other.

Answer (score 1):

You could make each div a separate gradient, I think. You could have Div 1 fade to halfway between black and blue from blue, and Div 2 fade from halfway to black. Then, as long as the div's edges are lined up, it should work!

You could use the gradient thing I mentioned above.

Here's my code. I used a hexadecimal color picker to get the value of the middle color. This version only works in safari, but you could change it to work in all browsers.

```
div:nth-child(1) {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(skyblue, #000066);
    height:150px;
    width:300px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
div:nth-child(2) {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#000066, black);
    height:150px;
    width:300px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be the blending of two divs? Or can you use something like this, with one gradient div and double the height?

```
div:nth-child(1) {
    background: linear-gradient(skyblue, black)
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

This might help: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp

Comment: Has to be two DIVs, unfortunately. Appreciate the thought, however! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

on way could be using an intermediate color like `rgb(71, 109, 124)`

and setting some `linear-gradient()` as `background` :

```
div:nth-child(1) {
    background: linear-gradient(skyblue 95%, rgb(71, 109, 124));
    height:150px;
    width:300px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
div:nth-child(2) {
    background: linear-gradient(rgb(71, 109, 124), black 5%);
    height:150px;
    width:300px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```